# How to design API - extend endpoint with query string or create new for single resource

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, endpoint

Old, one and only method in controller.

```java
// Cancel all shipments for specific item (beacuse from today selling companyX product is forbidden)
@PostMapping("/items/shipments/stop")
public List<String> stopShipmentsForItem(@RequestBody List<UUID> itemsUuids) {
    return itemShippingService.stopShipment(itemsUuids);
}
```

**Propose endpoint which stops specific shipping for specific item**

```java
// Extending existing one with query string
@PostMapping("/items/shipments/stop")
public List<String> stopShipmentsForItem(@RequestBody List<UUID> itemsUuids, @RequestParam(required = false) UUID shipmentUuid) {
    return itemShippingService.stopShipment(itemsUuids, shipmentUuid);
}
```

OR

```java
// Creating new one with path variables
@PostMapping("/items/{itemUuid}/shipments/{shipmentUuid}/stop")
public String stopShipmentForItem(@PathVariable UUID itemsUuid, @PathVariable UUID shipmentUuid) {
    return itemShippingService.stopShipment(itemsUuids, shipmentUuid);
}
```

**One opinion** - First option equals less code, it supports Open for extensions from SOLID, query string should be use for filtering and `UUID shipmentUuid` underneath in service is used for filtering purposes.

**Second opinion** - Second option is more reasonable as those are different actions and should be separated and be responsible for one type of action and as with i.e. getting resources from DB you probably will use different endpoints for one resource and all resources

Which approach do you think is better? - keep in mind that old endpoint should still works as previously after potential modification. 
Do you have any sources to prove that your opinion is correct?

Comment: IMO: Use the second option. If you retrieve something by and ID, it doesn't make sense to wrap that inside an array. The first option should be used solely for filtering a collection, i.e. only return results matching a condition, but not for retrieving a single element by an ID

Comment: Try a google search for "SQL Injection Attack".  Never accept SQL as an input parameter.

Comment: If you shipment can not be split into parts and/or shipment of each part can not be cancelled independently, why just do not add a new endpoint
/shipments/{shipmentUuid}/stop ?
Looks clearer for me and caller of your service needs to know only shipmentId